# how we remove multiple .html on url on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

im front of an error and i have search everywhere but didn't find the solution. I have multiple .html in my url on my wordpress website. Like = https://www.mywebsite.com/my-page.html.html.html

Can someone tell me where i can go for repair this ?

thanks

here is my .htaccess file, i tried to change it but didn't find the solution...

```
  

    
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/cache-manifest
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vcard
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-cross-domain-policy
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/manifest+json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/schema+json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.geo+json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    
    
    
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
        ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
        ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
        ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
        ExpiresByType text/html A3600
        ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
        ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
        ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
        ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
        ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
        ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
        ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
        ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
        ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
        ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
        ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
    
    
    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    
    AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
    
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
    # généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
    # Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    
    # END WordPress
```

Comment: is this a real page? when not why is it showing? Maybe a bug in the frontend or maybe somebody is funny and tried to see the page. their are many reasons why it can show up

Comment: It should not occur at all. Try the default WordPress .htaccess. Keep the old one and use the one in this link https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: its just an exemple link @Sysix

Comment: actually i have rewrite my url in function.php not in htaccess

Comment: @h.karam where it come frome? does is return a 404 response? when yes. nothing from wordpress should be wrong

Comment: no the page work. there is only multiple .html in the url

Comment: and i don't understand why there is .html whereas all my link are without html